# I want to add sheets into the excel file while without giving any names

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I was using interopt dll to add sheets into excel file but now i want to migrate to EPPlus. Here while adding new sheet we have to specify the name of the sheet but I wont EPPPlus to add sheet. I am using the following code:

```
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
pck.Save();
```

Here I am specifying the sheet name but I don't want to do that, it should add sheet on his own as there can be multiple sheet created. Is there any way I can achive this? 
Ex. if "Sheet1" is present it should automatically and "Sheet2" and add data to it.

Note: Even if I am adding New sheet is not giving any error but the excel sheet is grayed out. Nothing is coming up while opening the excel sheet.

Comment: Have you tried to just increment the sheet index by something like this? `ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($"Sheet{ pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Count + 1 }");`

Comment: Even after saving file, i am string to open file manually, it is giving error "the file is not in correct format". Is there any solution to this? @suppe

Comment: @Suppe please refer above comment